# Problem on validation in form array in angular

Tags: angular, validation, formarray

I have a problem on validation in form array. I have a assignment for validate the sum of `subQuota(formarray)` should be equal to total quota. The validation is correct when the page is `ngOnInit (subquota : 13,3,4 && totalquota: 20)`. However, when user want to click *"assign more quota"*, he add one more "2" `subquota (subquota : 13,3,4,2 && totalquota: 20)`, the error message will show immediately. When user noted that he is incorrect for total quota, he adjusted the total quota as *"22"* `(subquota : 13,3,4,2 && totalquota: 22)`. The message still show again althought the validation is correct. It seem to be not update the validation. What problem on it ?

[Here is code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-58i2zw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: when we have an input the value by defect is a "string", you can "cast" as number using a `+`:`enrolTypeList.reduce((a, b) => a + (+b.subQuota), 0);`

Comment: @Eliseo this is the worst solution, because it is only a dirty workaround. I have already written the good solution.

Comment: @PaRi, it's a personal conflict with "type number" (I hate the "caret by defect")

Comment: @Eliseo a senior suppose to fix the problem, not hiding it (in my opinion).

Comment: @PaRi, really I make a directive to input type number to force only digits, I use a 'null' to  use Validators.required, and is good two persons to have different opinions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1., Change the inputs' type from 'text' to 'number'**
in order to have e.g.: 4 (number) and not '4' (string) as the input value. You can't do 20 + '4', but 20 + 4 is a valid operation.

```
<input type="number" formControlName="subQuota">
<input type="number" formControlName="totalQuota">
```

**2., Change the default value from '' to 0 or null in addNewAssignQuota() function** in order to not have invalid input values at all, even if it is only the default value.

```
  control.push(
    this.fb.group({
      subQuota: [0],
    })
```

Comment: @cng then can you mark my comment as anser?:)